# Временные зоны php

Tags: часовые-пояса, временная-зона, php

Каким образом можно задать примерно так:

`date_default_timezone_set('Moscow');` а не `date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Moscow');` ?

и класс ipgeobase определяет город только на русском? Если нужно на английском, то как быть? Не редактировать же всё самому...

Т.е, **если Москва, то Moscow**, а не Moskva

Comment: Поясните, что такое ipgeobase, как он используется и что возвращает.

Comment: http://ipgeobase.ru/cgi-bin/Software.cgi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Этот класс делает запрос по адресу ipgeobase.ru:7020/geo?ip=IP, а там отдаётся XML по-русски. Если нужны английские имена, то имеет смысл посмотреть в сторону [GeoIP](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/), они же отдают и таймзону для региона (и, кстати, с IPv6 работают).

P.S. Поскольку комменты закончились - какие over9000 файлов? Только два: GeoIP.dat и GeoLiteCity.dat. А на JS:

```
var myDate = new Date();
var tz = myDate.getTimezoneOffset();
```

Comment: @klopp, лицензионный ключ нужно покупать?

Comment: Там есть ссылка на lite-версию базы для локального использования (но её надо будет периодически обновлять). А веб-сервис бесплатный.

Comment: А, стоп. Вроде веб-сервис за деньги, типа $20 за 50 тысяч запросов

Comment: @klopp, о боже. А какие ещё есть варианты? И я даже зарегаться не могу на сайте, не вижу где.

Comment: Вам $20 за 50000 запросов дорого? Качайте локальную базу.

Comment: @klopp, эта http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geolite ? Если да, то открыл её и такие дела - http://clip2net.com/clip/m40641/1352717745-clip-31kb.png . Как ней пользоваться то? И да, как там зарегистрироваться? Не могу найти.

Comment: http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/downloadable

Comment: @klopp, невыносимый бред. over 9000 ненужных файлов в каждой папке. Ключ можно купить только по paypal, а у меня его нет и не хочу с ним возиться тоже. На JS можно ли как-то определить time_zone?